# Executing python script from PHP(using apache XAMPP)

Tags: php, python, apache, shell, xampp

I am trying to execute a shell script containing python commands from PHP using exec function in Ubuntu 18.04. The issue is Python script is not able to create a file for writing data.

This is my shell script test.sh

`python3 p1.py`

This is my python script

```
with open('trial.txt','w') as file:
    file.write('Hello world')
```

This is my PHP script

```
<?php

try{
    $out=exec('test.sh',$output,$status);
    print_r($output);
}
catch(Exception $e)
{
    echo $e;
}?>
```

I am getting $status as 1. Is there any problem with apache user permissions? Current apache user is www-data. I have given permissions to python script using `chmod +x p1.py`. This shell script works correctly and creates a new file if it runs from ubuntu terminal. But when executing from PHP, it doesn't work properly.

Comment: Try and set absolute paths to your .sh, python3 binary and the python file. Do the same for the files in your file as well.

Comment: How do you execute the file from the terminal - did you add the dot-slash (if all in the same directory). 
This works for me `$out=exec('./test.sh',$output,$status);` (using php-cli in phpStorm). Without the dot-slash it returned - "sh: 1: test.sh: not found"

Comment: Try running it from the terminal with the user 'www-data' and see what error you might get then. Running it in terminal but with another user isn't a good idea for debugging.